# How to get excel file from disc in angular2 via rest

Tags: excel, rest, angular

I am using an angular 2 with Java background and communication between them is through REST. What I have to do is to create some excel file on button click and then to return that file in the user API.

REST looks like this:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/some_path/{someId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public FileSystemResource exportSomeData(@PathVariable long someId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ... create excel file data...
    File file = new File(fileName);
    response.addHeader("FILE_NAME", fileName);
    FileNameResource fsr = new FileNameResource(file);
    return fsr;
}`

In angular (return of the REST, call works ok):

`` getFile(path:String) {
    this.autthHttp.get(`some_path')
        .map((response) => {
            let blob = (response)['body'];
            return {
                data: new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), 
                filename: response.headers.get('FILE_NAME')
            }
        })
        .subscribe(res => saveAs(res.data, res.filename))
} ``

The problem is that I got the file, it contains data, but it lost it's metadata (show some question mark characters instead of format excel well in cells). Does somebody knows what can be the problem?

Comment: In RC5 I tried to change 
`let blob = (<any>response)['_body'];`
and
`data: new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/octet-stream'})`
with
`let blob = response.blob()`
and
`data: blob`
but then I got an exception _The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set the responseType to Blob and use RC5 blob response type:

```
getFile(path:String) {
this.autthHttp.get(`some_path', {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
    .map((response) => {
        let blob = response.blob();
        return {
            data: new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), 
            filename: response.headers.get('FILE_NAME')
        }
    })
    .subscribe(res => saveAs(res.data, res.filename))
```

}

Comment: Thank you. I am missing part `{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}`. Now it works.